# Письменная передача жаргонизма "харе"

Tags: жаргон

Заглянул в викисловарь, а там каша: споры, откаты страницы, противоречащие друг другу примеры употребления. Есть ли, от чего оттолкнуться, чтобы записать "харе" правильно? И как правильно:

- Харе
- Харэ
- Хоре
- Хорэ

Лично я склоняюсь к первому варианту. Хотя он и создаёт путаницу с словом "харя" (в д.п.) и с "Харе Кришна", но кажется наиболее точным.

Comment: Думаю, что вопрос "как правильно" некорректен, если слова нет в академических словарях. Я бы взял первый или второй вариант, но обозначил бы ударение.

Comment: @tum_ отличная мысль на счёт ударения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ― Только заедем на Папанина. ― Харэ! Сорок четвертый дом представлял
>   из себя блочную пятиэтажку, в которой располагалось малосемейное
>   общежитие завода «Алмаз». [Даниил Корецкий. Менты не ангелы, но…
>   (2011)]
>
> ― Ну хватит, харэ! ― прервал излияния восторгов Толя Крез и сказал,
>   что пора делом заняться, ему нужны стихи о любви, он намерен
>   опубликовать их под своим именем в какой-нибудь из новых местных газет
>   для цензурного авторитета их фирмы. [Виктор Слипенчук. Зинзивер
>   (2001)]
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
>
> (Урал, Выпуски 9-12. Свердловское книжное изд-во, 2007)

Вариант, к которому склоняетесь, то будет слово склоняемое. Оно представлено в литературе гораздо шире.